# Meta type of dictionary

Tags: swift, types, protocols

I want to write a function that accepts any type to determine to do its job. but I encounter error with dictionary.type. it requests a specific type for the key of its placeholder.

is it any way I can do that?

as I may use like that:

```
foo(type: type(of: someDict)) // someDict can be any type of dictionary.
// can be [String: Any] or [Int, Any] or [Double: Any] or [Character: Any], etc. 


func foo(type: Any.Type) {
    switch type {
    case is Int.Type:
        print("is Int")
    //case is Dictionary: // error, Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <...>
    case is Dictionary<Hashable, Any>: // also error, Using 'Hashable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported
        print("is Dictionary")
    default:
        print("don't know")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `Any` as the type of the input argument to your function. Rather you should make your function generic.

To solve the issue with matching `Dictionary`'s metatype, you should simply change `Hashable` to `AnyHashable`, which is the type-erased container type for a `Hashable` value.

```
func foo<T>(type: T.Type) {
    switch type {
    case is Int.Type:
        print("is Int")
    case is Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>.Type:
        print("is Dictionary")
    default:
        print("don't know")
    }
}
```

Comment: can't as I am going to write like that: func load(dict: [String: Any.Type]) -> [String:Any]

Comment: so, I will pass like: ["IntKey": Int.self, "StringKey": String.self]

Comment: While this will compile it doesn't appear to identify dictionaries correctly.  If I have a [String: Any] or [Int: Any] and pass it type(of: varName) it doesn't identify it as a dictionary.  Only a var of type [AnyHashable: Any] directly works.  (It's the approach I was trying)

Comment: oh! then, I don't have to write <T>. seems like  AnyHashable works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should work with `Any` not with `Any.Type`? This works fine:

```
let dict: [Int: Any] = [:]
foo(type: dict) // is Dictionary
foo(type: 12) // is Int
foo(type: "12") // don't know

func foo(type: Any) {
    switch type {
    case is Int:
        print("is Int")
    case is Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>:
        print("is Dictionary")
    default:
        print("don't know")
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, I am writing a function to load data using "UserDefaults.standard". so, there is no value I can pass to. I can only tell the type and the key to select the proper method to load the data.